# MQTT data not writing to DynamoDB table with AWS IoT

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, mqtt, iot, aws-iot

I am new to AWS IoT and am trying to log data from an Arduino sensor to a DynamoDB table as shown here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-ddb-rule.html

The shadow data is being updated on a Thing called Volume, but the data is not being written to the table. I am not sure if I have correctly defined my topic which I am calling my/Volume because of the thing name. Here is its ARN:

arn:aws:iot:us-west-2:468820349153:thing/Volume

A basic test insert using the IoT test MQTT client was able to insert data into the table.  I created a rule called VolumeRule with this query: SELECT * FROM 'my/Volume'.

Thanks for your help,

Steve

Answer (score 0):

can you please cross-check the topic on which you are publishing, the  topic name should be same in the rule query i.e "SELECT * FROM 'my/Volume'" then your topic should be my/Volume .

i am providing you a step

1. make a rule SELECT * FROM 'my/Volume'
2. attach action "Split message into multiple columns of a DynamoDB table (DynamoDBv2)" and specify the table name
3. publish the data on the topic "my/Volume"
4. that's it its done , data would have saved in our table